# How to edit app.properties file with build parameter in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, testng

I have a selenium script which I want to run from Jenkins. I have a properties file called app.properties. This file consists properties such as:

```
browser=chrome
```

I configured my project as parameterized so when I run my build, it asks for browser parameter. I want to select this parameter(for example firefox), so that it will change browser property in app.properties and will run the automation in Firefox.

Normally, when I change the browser property in app.properties in Intellij, my program runs with that browser. So there is nothing wrong with my program in that sense.

Is there a way to change app.properties with respect to my Jenkins build parameter and run the program with that configuration?

EDIT: I found the following solution:

1. Install surefire plugin.
2. Add a browser parameter.
3. In your property managing class, take browser parameter as

   System.getProperty("browser");
4. From jenkins, configure a browser parameter
5. Invoke maven command: mvn test "-Dbrowser=${BROWSER}"

Comment: You will have to pass the argument to your maven task that you are invoking `-Drun.jvmArguments="-Dbrowser=chrome"`. And the "chrome" value could be injected from jenkins using variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass system properties to change configuration.
First you should configure your project to read both system properties and configuration file, where system properties will have higher priority. I'd recommend Apache Commons [Composite Configuration](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_compositeconfiguration.html#Composite_Configuration_Details). It can look like this:

```
CompositeConfiguration configuration = new CompositeConfiguration();
try {
  configuration.addConfiguration(new SystemConfiguration());
  configuration.addConfiguration(new PropertiesConfiguration("app.properties"));
} catch (ConfigurationException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
//Read your configuration values here
```

This way when you provide system property **-Dbrowser=chrome** it will override value from configuration file.

Secondly, you'll need to configure Jenkins job. Since you're passing a parameter you can use it in your build step definition:

```
mvn clean test -Dbroswer=${browser-param}
```

Comment: I went with another solution but this is a very nice approach as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

“The way parameters take effect is also different depending on the parameter type you choose ... String parameters are exposed as environment variables of the same name.”
https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=34930782#content/view/34930782